# Trying to insert Date into Oracle Database via php but Code isint working

Tags: php, html, mysql, oracle

im creating a project and im having problems inserting the date into the oracle database , i am using data binding ,everything else works but date isint getting inserted ..

```
$bkida = @$_POST['bkida'];
$titlea = @$_POST['titlea'];
$athr = @$_POST['athr'];
$pblr = @$_POST['pblr'];
$edtn = @$_POST['edtn'];
$btype = @$_POST['btype'];
$pdatea = @$_POST['pdatea'];
$indatea = @$_POST['indatea'];
$tbooks = @$_POST['tbooks'];
$tpages = @$_POST['tpages'];

$cmts = @$_POST['cmts'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO books(ISBN,   TITLE, AUTHOR,PUBLISHER,EDITION,BK_TYPE,PRINT_DT,   IN_DT,     TOT_BKS,  AVAIL_BKS,  PAGES,  COMMENTS) 
"."VALUES(:bkida,:titlea,:athr,:pblr,     :edtn,  :btype  ,to_date(:pdatea, 'MM-DD-YYYY'), to_date(:indatea, 'MM-DD-YYYY'),  :tbooks ,  :tbooks,  :tpages ,  :cmts   )";

$compiled = oci_parse($conn, $sql);

oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':bkida', $bkida);
oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':titlea', $titlea);
oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':athr', $athr);
oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':pblr', $pblr);
oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':edtn', $edtn);
oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':btype', $btype);

oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':pdatea', $pdatea);
oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':indatea', $indatea);
oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':tbooks', $tbooks);
oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':tpages', $tpages);
oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':cmts', $cmts);


oci_execute($compiled);
```

Comment: what is the datatype of your db??

Comment: i have set it to  DATE  ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default date format will be `YYYY-MM-DD`, I think you are trying to insert in some other format. Convert your date like this before inserting to database

```
$pdatea = date("Y-m-d",strtotime(@$_POST['pdatea']));
$indatea = date("Y-m-d",strtotime(@$_POST['indatea']));
```

Comment: alright i'll try this ..but when i was inserting directly into database via oracle panel , i had to insert in this format MM-DD-YYYY , 12-20-2015 ,  because it was not accepting any other format .

Comment: was the datatype date for that column??

Comment: That isint working too , i am using oracle 11g ... i put the date as 2015-10-10 in the text box to update and it still does not work , i also tried 10-10-2015 but no success ..

Comment: what is getting inserted in db??

Comment: if i leave the 2 date text boxes ( pdatea and indatea )  blank , every other column gets updated but if i try to fill in date nothing get inserted .

Comment: echo the query and check what is that printing.

Answer (score 1):

Solved , after i used echo i gt a weird output , so i played with the values of y-m-d and finally got this code to work

```
$pdatea = date("m-d-Y",strtotime(@$_POST['pdatea']));
indatea = date("m-d-Y",strtotime(@$_POST['indatea']));
```

Thanks Mr Niranjan for the help :D